# how to get id for specific car in select statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to display all car names,their images ,rental rate all from different tables in a page. How do I get id for each car in select statement?

for instance:

```
while($row_showall = mysql_fetch_array($result_showall))
{
      $car_id[] = $row_showall['carName_id'];
}
foreach($car_id as $id)
{
      $id;
      echo $id.'<br/>';
      //result is 
      27773
      27774
      27778
      27779
}
```

when I place $id outside foreach loop obviously it doesn't loop and the result is 
2779.

so when I use select statement here like this:

```
$query_showdays_1="SELECT ........WHERE car_name.carName_id='$id'";
```

how do I make it select each and every of the car id instead of only one id?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you need to look into `JOIN`'s so that you can get all information in 1 database query.

Comment: remove `WHERE car_name.carName_id='$id'` to select all ids.

Comment: Side note: you should use PDO or MYSQLi with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your table name is cars, because you haven't provided that info. If it's not then change the cars with your table name.

```
$query_showdays_1 = "SELECT * FROM cars";

while ($row_showall = mysql_fetch_array($query_showdays_1))
{
    echo $row_showall['carName_id'] . '<br />';
}
```